# Get the name of operands of a code from bytecode

Tags: analysis, bytecode, javassist

I'm analyzing the bytecode of a class.
I can detect the opcode and the operands of it.
How can I get the the name of this (the name of the object)

For istance the opcode is new and i have as operand an integer  (think a the follow code: "new String()")
Where I should serch for the name? In the constantPool of the class and how?
I'm not expert

Answer (score 0):

[ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) is the best choice. It is fast and has simple API and detailed [User Guide](http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm-guide.pdf). The framework completely abstracts you from dealing with constant pool and other class format structures.